# Calling a Static Method with AsyncTask/ProgressDialog of a class

Tags: android, static, android-asynctask, progressdialog, static-methods

So I'm relatively new to Android (and Java). I've made a class which has your usual `AsyncTask` with a ProgressDialog in a `static` method because I want to call it from multiple Activities.

```
public class SomeClass {

    // Some other methods, etc.

    public static void SomeFunction(final Context context, String FilePath) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            private ProgressDialog dialog;

            protected void onPreExecute() {
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Loading...", true); 
            }

            protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) { 
                for (int i=0; i<15000; i++) 
                    System.out.println("Gatorade me, Bitch: " + i);

            return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) { 
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        }.execute();  
    }

}
```

The problem is that the statement 
`dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Loading...", true);`
in the `onPreExecute()` section of the `AsyncTask` gives error. The code runs fine without it.

So what can I do to solve this issue without creating a new java class file for AsyncTask. I know that works but I just want to make one file for this entire class so I can use it in multiple programs.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: the constructor should be called on the ui thread, you can after call execute() anywhere, but you should instantiate the async task in the ui thread, you can make a static method that creates the asynctask instance for you

Comment: Its working fine ... i run your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether you are passing application context or activity context while calling the function.

With application context, you cannot show the Progress Bar. If thats the case, try passing activity context.

```
SomeFunction(ActivityName.this,"path");
```